# Disabling unwanted logging - Serilog, .Net 6 Minimal API

Tags: .net, serilog

I'd like to get rid of unwanted logging. I managed to filter out most of it using the following configuration of Serilog:

```
 "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command": "Error",
            "Microsoft": "Debug",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure": "Warning"
        }
    },
```

But still I'm getting something like this:

```
[2023-05-07 15:08:38.576 +02:00  INF]  Executing endpoint HTTP: GET HeartBeat/{iddevice}/{status}/{version?}
[2023-05-07 15:08:38.578 +02:00  INF]  Entity Framework Core 6.0.6 initialized Context using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.0 with options: None
[2023-05-07 15:08:38.594 +02:00  INF]  Executed endpoint HTTP: GET HeartBeat/{iddevice}/{status}/{version?}
```

Each time any API Method is invoked. I'm tracing some kind of a bug and I'd like to have only my own explicit logging. Which overrides I should add to disable it?

Comment: You have default Microsoft log to `Debug` - `"Microsoft": "Debug"`, set it to `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all logs from Microsoft - just specify the "root" category to `Error` or `None`:

```json
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.File", "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "None"
        }
     }
}
```

As explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#configure-logging):

> The `"Microsoft"` category applies to all categories that start with `"Microsoft"`

And the most specific category is used when determining the log level (so if you will need logs from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics` you can add them explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

To remove logs from certain Sources you can use expression filters. Your code could look like this

```
    "WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3} {Application}] {Message:lj} {NewLine}{Exception}",
    },
    "configureLogger": {
      "Filter": [
        {
          "Name": "ByExcluding",
          "Args": {
            "expression": "@Level = 'Error' and UploadError is not null"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Importantly, using a filter can restrict based on the content of the message, but this means that the message must be processed.  If logging a very noisy thing, using an override is recommended so that the content does not have to be processed to be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Serilog hasn't `MinimumLevel: None`.
Replace to:

```
"Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Information"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).